# Build failure Oozie distro creation failed

Tags: apache, maven, hadoop, oozie, distro

/mkdistro -DskipTests -Dhadoopversion=2.6.0 to build oozie distro and I am getting the following error. Please help.

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.321s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 15 12:13:27 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 54M/420M
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.1.0: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1 (compile), org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.6.0.oozie-4.1.0 (provided), org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.6.0.oozie-4.1.0 (test), junit:junit:jar:4.10 (test), org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-utils:jar:2.6.0.oozie-4.1.0 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.6.0.oozie-4.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:pom:2.6.0.oozie-4.1.0 from/to Codehaus repository (http://repository.codehaus.org/): repository.codehaus.org: Unknown host repository.codehaus.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Maven can't reach

> repository.codehaus.org

because it has been shut down.

Check out the [latest pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/pom.xml#L125) and replace the  part in your pom.xml with the latest one. It should work that way.